Is there a better way to iterate over nested tables here?
I am constructing a dedicated bridging service across Discord, Revolt, and two separate IRC networks. I'm attempting to do so somewhat anonymously, as I want the service to be easily configurable for other individuals with the same need.
On evaluating the bridged channels, discord and revolt are straightforward. However, IRC presents a more challenging scenario, as the separate IRC configurations are not explicitly named and instead presented as a collection.
I have constructed a configuration like so:
[[bridge]]
    [bridge.chat]
    discord = "<discord-channel-id>"
    revolt = "<revolt-channel-id>"
    libera = "#<channel-name>"
    oftc = "#<channel-name>"

Here, no key is necessarily mandatory. additionally, the keys libera and oftc can be the titles of any network, providing they are specified earlier in the configuration.
Since the key may or may not exist, and may contain any previously specified name, I constructed an anonymous type definition for the bridge service:
public class bridges
{
    string bridgeName = "";

    Dictionary<string, string> ircChannels = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string revoltChannel = "";
    ulong discordChannel = 0;
    bool hasIrcConnection = false;
    ...
    //getters/setters
    ...
}

Then, I iterate through the configuration (which is presented as a nested table of nested tables of nested tables and so on), extracting the appropriate data, and filling up an instantiation of bridges that can then be added to a list of the same:
Note: This is part of a larger switch-case where the initial connections are defined
case "bridge":
    foreach(TomlTable table in tArr)
    {
        foreach(string tableKey in table.Keys)
        {
            bridges bridge = new bridges();
            bridge.BridgeName = tableKey;
            foreach(var item in (TomlTable)table[bridge.BridgeName])
            {
                switch (item.Key)
                {
                    case "discord":
                        bridge.DiscordChannel = (ulong)item.Value;
                        break;
                    case "revolt":
                        bridge.RevoltChannel = (string)item.Value;
                        break;                                                
                }
                foreach (string server in ircCommunityNames)
                //    note: ircCommunityNames is a list of strings 
                //    filled in the earlier connection evaluation 
                //    methods. In this case, it could be demonstrated
                //    in written code as: ["libera", "oftc"]
                {
                    if(server == item.Key)
                    {
                        bridge.IrcChannels.Add(server, (string)item.Value);
                    }  
                }

            }
            if(bridge.IrcChannels.Count > 0)
            {
                bridge.HasIrcConnection = true; //Avoids unnecessary evaluation of the enumerable
            }
            bridgeConfigs.Add(bridge);

        }
    }
    break;

I'd like to ideally avoid using multiple evaluation approaches inside one another. Using foreach to iterate over the same key-value pair that has just been tested in a switch-case feels inefficient. Is there a better approach here?

The code snippet you've posted can be rewritten using the following LINQ-query
case "bridge":
    var bc = tAttr.SelectMany(table => table.Keys.Select(k => new { Key = k, Table = table }))
        .Select(tableKey => new {
            BridgeName = tableKey.Key,
            DiscordChannel = ((TomlTable)tableKey.Table[bridge.BridgeName])
                .LastOrDefault(item => item.Key == "discord")?.Value as ulong,
            RevoltChannel = ((TomlTable)tableKey.Table[bridge.BridgeName])
                .LastOrDefault(item => item.Key == "revolt")?.Value as string,
            IrcChannels = ((TomlTable)tableKey.Table[bridge.BridgeName])
                .SelectMany(item => ircCommunityNames
                    .Where(server => server == item.Key)
                    .ToDictionary(server => server, server => (string)item.Value)
                )
                .ToList(),
        })
        .Select(b => {
            return new bridges {
                BridgeName = b.BridgeName,
                DiscordChannel = b.DiscordChannel,
                RevoltChannel = b.RevoltChannel,
                HasIrcConnection = (b.IrcChannels.Count > 0),
                IrcChannels = b.IrcChannels,
            };
        });
    bridgeConfigs.AddRange(bc);
    break;


is it possible to avoid lambda expressions in linq? I hate how difficult to read they make code.

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you want to avoid writing code for every combination of platforms.
You can do this by providing a common format for all platforms as well as logic for translating from these platforms to the format and from that format to the platforms you want to bridge.
//define a platform-independent format (just an example)
class Message {
  public Message(string content, string authorName, int channelId) =>
    (Content, AuthorName, ChannelId) = (content, authorName, channelId);
 
  public string Content { get; }
  public string AuthorName { get; }
  public int ChannelId { get; }
}

//define an interface for platforms
interface IPlatform {
    void SendMessage(Message message);
}

Each platform would then have its own logic to send messages. These platform implementations can then make use of your configuration:
class BridgeConfiguration{
    public List<ChannelConfiguration> Channels { get; }
}
class ChannelConfiguration{
    public string DiscordChannelId { get; }
    public string IRCChannelName { get; }
    //...
}

class Discord : IPlatform {
    private Bridge bridge;

    //TODO initialize these dictionaries
    private IDictionary<int, DiscordChannel> genericChannelToDiscordChannel = new Dictionary<>();
    private IDictionary<DiscordChannel, int> discordChannelToGenericChannel = new Dictionary<>();
    public Discord(Bridge bridge, BridgeConfiguration config) {
        registerOnMessageReceived(onMessageReceived);//however you do this for your platforms
        this.bridge = bridge;

        //set up the dictionaries using a configuration object
        for(int i = 0; i < config.Channels.Count; i++) {
            var discordChannel = getDiscordChannelById(config.Channels[i].DiscordChannelId);
            genericChannelToDiscordChannel[i] = discordChannel;
            discordChannelToGenericChannel[discordChannel] = i;
        }
    }
    void IPlatform.SendMessage(Message message) {
        //convert the message to Discord's format and send it
        sendDiscordMessage(message.Content, message.AuthorName);
        //TODO handle case where mapping doesn't contain message.ChannelId
        genericChannelToDiscordChannel[message.ChannelId].sendMessage(message.Content, message.AuthorName);
    }
    void onMessageReceived(DiscordMessage message) {
        //transform the message
        var genericMessage = new Message(message.ContentRaw, message.Member.DisplayName, discordChannelToGenericChannel[message.Channel.Id]);
        //publish the message
        bridge.PublishMessage(genericMessage);
    }
}

and when receiving a message in one service, you find the platform(s)/service(s) you want to repost the message at and call their SendMessage methods.
public class Bridge {
    private IList<IPlatform> platforms = new List<>();
    public static void Main() {
        new Bridge().run(readConfiguration());
    }
    private void run(BridgeConfiguration config) {
        platforms.Add(new Discord(this, config));
        platforms.Add(new OtherPlatform(this, config));
    }
    public void PublishMessage(Message message){
        foreach (Platform platform in platforms) {
            platform.SendMessage(messgage);
        }
    }
}

Alternatively, you might want to take a look at events for a more elegant/concise solution that's doing mostly the same thing.

I like the idea of a platform-agnostic bridge, but it doesn't quite suit every use-case - particularly in our scenario, as I require a few interim adjustments to messages in order to enable platform-specific notifications. Add to this the annoyance of one library using events for tasks, and the other using tasks for events, and it makes it doubly difficult.
My real intention here was to find some simpler way of evaluating the TOML table, whilst maintaining configuration agnosticism and not evaluating the table inside an evaluation of that same table. Part of this is also deciding on ...

... what IRC channel to join, which is where the explicitly defined separate bridges come into play. We have two separate IRC channels involved, per IRC server, and that's on top of the evaluation of messages prior to bridging.
Nevertheless, I do like the idea of an agnostic approach to receiving messages, which I think I may use as opposed to my MessageBlock approach which was rather clunky.

I would still try to use an agnostic approach like (for the IRC channel issue) keeping a (two-sided) mapping between IRC channels and channel information in the generic message variant. In that case, the IRC IPlatform implementation could have a Dictionary mapping from IRC channels to generic channel IDs which is used when an IRC message is received and a Dictionary in the reverse direction which is used when sending a message into the IRC. The TOML configuration could then list these mappings in some form. However, you need to decide what should happen if a message is missing a mapping.

I added something like that to my answer. I would really try to not write code for every platform my first transforming everything to an agnostic format and then transforming that to the format you need. Without that, you would need to have 20 implementations for 5 platforms or 90 implementations for 10 platforms (assuming you don't need anything for a platform communicating with itself).
